# Exclude the first table before converting all the tables to text

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am using this code to convert all tables to text, but I want to exclude the first table (which contains the Heading of the file) and convert the remaining to text.

How do I change the code and put counter on tables.

```
Dim tbl As Table
For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
    tbl.ConvertToText Separator:=wdSeparateByTabs
Next tbl
Set tbl = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this code with different type of loop:

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = ActiveDocument.Tables.Count To 2 Step -1
    ActiveDocument.Tables(i).ConvertToText Separator:=wdSeparateByTabs
Next i
```